# I can't access my desktop (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10

Whenever I press the windows key it brings me to the tablet app menu instead of my desktop. When I try to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> it shows my open tasks, but no desktop.

Minimizing tasks only brings me to the tablet app menu. I just can't get to my desktop. I also have no task shortcuts on my bottom left anymore, only a windows icon, a back arrow, a search icon, and the app menu.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 is "intelligent" about which mode you use - touch screen (tablet mode) or mouse/keyboard - desktop and it optimizes for each use. What you are describing is tablet mode being turned on all the time. In order to fix, start be verifying your settings:

[image]

if all of it looks correct i..e your kids or you didn't accidentally changed it, you should verify your device is correctly docked so it knows it's not in tablet mode. That would be HW specific, you didn't say what device you are using....